# TCL/TK support in R 4.1.1

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

I would like to have TLC/TK support in R 4.1.1 (on a Linux Ubuntu machine).
What additional packages shall I install ?

```
 > capabilities()
           jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua 
           TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE 
       http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
           TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
            NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
           TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

Comment: Looks like it's part of the R compilation: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Tcl_002fTk

Comment: I have re-configured R with tcl-tk support : ./configure --with-tcltk, however, I am still getting the error below. I am using Ubuntu operating system. S3 methods ‘as.character.tclObj’, ‘as.character.tclVar’, ‘as.double.tclObj’, ‘as.integer.tclObj’, ‘as.logical.tclObj’, ‘as.raw.tclObj’, ‘print.tclObj’, ‘[[.tclArray’, ‘[[<-.tclArray’, ‘$.tclArray’, ‘$<-.tclArray’, ‘names.tclArray’, ‘ ‘tclObj.tclVar’, ‘tclObj<-.tclVar’, ‘tclvalue.default’, ‘tclvalue.tclObj’, ‘tclvalue.tclVar’, ‘tclvalue<-.default’, ‘tclvalue<-.tclVar’, ‘close.tkProgressBar’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found

Comment: partially solved by doing : sudo apt-get install -y libmagick++-dev on Ubuntu ;

Comment: also doing install : sudo apt-get install tcllib on Ubuntu

Comment: and install.packages("tcl") in R